# Why are autocomplete not working for React Native in WebStorm?

Tags: react-native, webstorm, stylesheet

I am writing React Native code using WebStorm. When I am writing auto suggestion for code is not working. I have tried following steps: it's working for some syntax and not for other:

- Go to `Settings->(Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Languages & Frameworks`
- Expand `JavaScript->Library`
- When using React, I suggest to add: `react , react-dom, react-native` (if you interested in mobile dev)
- Click Apply when you done

I have tried above but the issue is at while writing `styles`

```
container: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 200,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
}
```

it is not showing suggestion for `'space-between'` in `justifyContent` and `row/column` in `flexDirection` etc.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-38735](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38735) for updates